# Door opening 3D effect in CSS

Tags: css, 3d

I'm trying to create a "door opening" 3D effect in CSS but I just can't do it. The problem is that using rotateY() function makes the element spin. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/uC4du/1/

Do you know how to change the rotateY "reference axis"? What should I do to make the element rotate using its left corners as reference?

Comment: One option is to make the parent object twice as wide, with half being blank. Then as it flips on its center axis, the part that is visible appears to be acting like a door.

Comment: @DA Yes I did, but it will make everything much harder :(

Comment: Check this out it will be helpful http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/19/experimental-css3-animations-for-image-transitions/ tympanus.net/Development/ImageTransitions/index2.html

Comment: To get a more natural door opening effect, put the "perspective" property on a parent element, along with setting the "transform-origin-y" to "left". You can see it here in your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uC4du/273/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use 'transform-origin' property ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp ).

Set it to something like: "-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;"

Here is your example using that property: http://jsfiddle.net/aV76H/

Hope it helps!

Comment: One little update to get exactly what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/aV76H/2054/
The original version had a weird effect on the top part, this is a symmetric version.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, but could anyone point me in the right direction to modify this to work on Firefox?