# change height of one side of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an animation of the effect of an opening door.  Is there any known algortihms for doing this?  If not, I need to alter a rectangular div making the right side longer than the left side, and the top and bottom lines connecting the right to left side of the div would be diagonal, and the contents of the div, are stretched proportionally.  Is there a way to change the height properties like so, for a div?

Comment: Use [CSS3 3D Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)?

Comment: Door opening 3D effect in CSS http://stackoverflow.com/a/8853933/1102223 Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aV76H/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css "transform" property, if you don't need to support older browsers.

Have a look at the [w3c specification](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp) |  [mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms), and also at this tutorials: [css 3d tutorial series](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/).

An alternative solution for older browsers would be a [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), which is more supported (still not in all browsers).

If you need to support almost all browsers, you could use flash, but I really not recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS Transform however it won't support older browsers.
Here is a good tutorial for that: http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Your best bet is making an animation using several images and changing them.